# How to reenable Intellisense/suggestions in VS Code (I may have accidentally removed the program's path for the dictionary

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I hope I'm using the correct terms here. In VS Code, I messed up the program's Intellisense. It no longer shows most methods/options/suggestions (specifically for Javascript, I haven't tried others. If I type 'consol' in an empty .js file, nothing pops up. If I type 'console.l' it will suggest 'console.log'. But if I type 'console.', it won't suggest anything at all. It used to, but I think I wrecked something when I was messing with deep program settings, trying to disable them (the wrong way).

What I'm looking for is this:
[code suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuMJ7.png)
VS Code used to give Javascript suggestions like these, when typing built-in Javascript components, like Date, or Console.
But now, it only suggests things you've already typed, but that's about it. The same code from above (the date), looks like this in VS Code:
[vs code lacking suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUjNy.png)

Nothing pops up when I get that '.' after the variable name. No methods or suggestions whatsoever.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how to re-enable it, but a good approach for many problems like these is to uninstall completely (including stuff in AppData), then reinstall

Comment: Your comment actually fixed my issue. I'd tried uninstalling in the past, but I didn't think to delete the AppData. That did the trick, and using Settings Sync, I was able to keep all my preferences. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application isn't behaving as it did when originally installed, an approach that often fixes the problem is to uninstall the application and all of its saved settings, and then to reinstall it. It's not quite a magic bullet, but it works more often than not, in my experience.

For VSCode, at least on Windows, you can uninstall it by going too:

**Settings -> Apps -> Microsoft Visual Studio Code**

, and once that's done, you can delete the cached settings by navigating to:

**C:\Users<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming**

and deleting the **Code** folder.

If you want to save your settings first so you don't have to re-apply each of them, you can [sync them](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync) to the cloud with a Microsoft or Github account, then re-sync when VSCode is reinstalled. (But, keep in mind that doing that introduces a greater possibility of the problem persisting, just in case the problem is caused by one of your settings.)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't modified any settings before, you can download some useful intellisense plugins, such as **VS Code JavaScript(ES6) snippets, JavaScript Snippet Pack, JavaScript Snippets**, etc.

If the settings have been modified, you can open the settings, search for **"suggestions"/"snippet"**, and check the options there.

You can see this for more information : [enter link description here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_intellisense)

Answer (score -1):

at vscode marketplace, you can reinstall intellisense and fix that maybe.